# How to copy paste "Design view" from Access to excel?

Tags: ms-access

I go to "Design view" of a given table and just want to copy/paste what I see into an excel sheet.

The solutions I saw suggest "Database Documenter", but if we include "Properties" it exports way too much data. Another method suggests some .mdb files, but examples I see are all 32bit, so I'm a bit stuck..

Have been at it for over an hour and this inability to copy/paste data we see (from a screen that looks a lot like excel) into actual excel sheet is strange to say the least...

[image]

Comment: MS Access is not MS Excel. Have a look at this thread: [How to export a table definition into Excel - Access World Forums](https://access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=153318)

Comment: @Rene thanks for clarifying, I was 100% sure MS Access is Excel... :) I checked the thread, but it looks like I need to implement some kind of a MS access code

Comment: Funny and witty reply, made me laugh out loud :) Yes, you'd have to write a bit of VBA code. I guess there's plenty of examples in the link I provided.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Goto Ribbon Database Tools
2. Click Database Documenter
3. Select the table
4. Click Options

   a. De_Select all of "Include for table"

   b. Select "Nothing" of "Include for Indexes"

   c. Select "Names, Data Types, and Sizes" of "Include for Fields"
5. OK.
6. Click "Excel" in the Ribbon to Export to Excel.

Comment: You just saved me time and potential errors in re-typing all the field neames. The only thing missing is the description field - but can get that if you select "Names, Data Types, Sizes, and Properties"